# Detail Missing on Case

Tags: community, servicecloud

Good day
When i'm trying to pass a case to a queue, the details that was save on the case like address, account name, etc.. suddenly disappear. Im still new on service cloud and i dont know which part ill look to fix this.
Thanks

Comment: Please check if the user has FLS permission for those fields and also make sure your fields are added in the page layout

Comment: yes it is added.. it was like.. User 1.. created a case then filled it up like address..contact no. then he saved it.. and pass it on the queue.. when User 2 got the case from the queue.. address and contact no. is missing and thus user 2..need to fill it up again...

Comment: That means your values are not getting saved in Salesforce if that user is seeing blank values

Comment: Yep.. that what i was thinking.. is this a system problem?.. bug?.. or is there a way to fix it?...

Answer (score 0):

Can you check if data is available in back-end using developer console or workbench, if yes then please check the page layout assignment to the user's profile from which you are viewing the case after assigning it to the queue and FLS too for that profile.

Comment: Will check on that.. it will take time.. cause im using salesforce for 2 months now.. and the idiot company just gave me only a system admin training....